# Why can't I set the Office365 sender name remotely when sending via smtp?

Tags: outlook, smtp, office365

An external saas application "SocialNetwork" is using one of our office365 users to send the notification emails. Typically the saas app will send different notifications and will set the sender name to the author of a new content. But the sender name for the notifications is always the name of the Office365 user ("SocialNetwork").

e.g.:
John Doe posts a new file in the saas application "SocialNetwork". I should receive an email notification about that. The notification is sent via our Office365 user "SocialNetwork". Sadly the email I receive as a Office365 user comes from "SocialNetwork" and not as "John Doe", which is set when the notification email is sent.

How can we send notifications via an office365 user but still not have a fixed name for this user and rather send emails with it including varying sender names?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange Server in general, and Office 365 in particular, will not let you spoof the sender address. It has to come from one of the SMTP aliases of the mailbox.